# retrieving last inserted ID of a table for using as Foreign key in another table

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, identifier

I have table(table1 and table2) that ID of table1 are foreign key of table2. in INSERT I want to save last ID inserted in table1 for insert to foreign key of  table2.
In your idea what is best way for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Like this in Your Code:

```
$result= mysql_query("Your SelectQuery");   
$lastId  = mysql_insert_id();
```

And Use `$lastId` variable . And You Can Get Your `REsult`.

You Can Also Use `JOIN`s For join 2 tables And use `last_insert_id` for table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function, to get the last inserted auto incremented column's value.

Comment: In table2 I have ID, LAST_INSERT_ID() return table1's ID, Or table2's ID?

Comment: Can I save LAST_INSERT_ID(); to a variable?

Comment: @Ehsan After you did the insert into the first table that has the auto_increment column, `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and save it into a variable, then take this value and insert it to the other table into the foriegn key column.